# VueJS: update variable in data dynamically

Tags: vue.js, jsonschema

I'm working with VueJS library to generate form from a JSON schema, the library work great beside one issue, if I'm loading the JSON directly from the data() I can see the form content perfectly:
https://codepen.io/eran-levi/pen/wvGVBGJ

(here is the Schema JSON inside data()):

```
schema: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        stringProp: {
            type: 'string',
            title: 'I\'m a string',
            description: 'This description is used as a help message.'
        }
    }
}
```

But, once I'm trying to load it dynamically (I'm loading the data and only then update it), in this case I cant see anything on page, see it here:
https://codepen.io/eran-levi/pen/WNwVbGZ

(Here is how I'm trying to update the field):

```
created() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('Component has been created!');
                    
        this.schema.properties.stringProp = {
            type: 'string',
            title: 'I\'m a string',
            description: 'This description is used as a help message.',
        }                        
    }, 3000); 
}
```

Can you please explain why I can not update the field dynamically and see it right away?

Thank you!

Comment: Context issue, uses `setTimeout(() => {...}, }` instead of `function () {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way Vue reactivity works. The properties `type`, `title` and `description` won't be reactive, because they don't exist when the instance is first initialised and it walks the `schema` object and wraps it to make it reactive to changes. Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion - more on that can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

To make it work, you have a couple of options. You can use `Vue.set` as below, which will tell Vue there's a new property that needs to be made reactive. That would look like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.$set(this.schema.properties, 'stringProp', {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'I\'m a string',
        description: 'This description is used as a help message.',
    });
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

Alternative, you could change the initial declaration to include the properties you need. That means your initial data would look like this:

```
data: {
    model,
    options,
    schema: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
            stringProp: { type: null, title: null, description: null },
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, works perfectly, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you forgot comma after created hook and you updating `properties` instead `properties.stringProp` like in the first example. In order to update `properties.stringProp` you need to set it previously to `null`.

```
schema: {
    type: "object",
    properties: { stringProp: null },
},

updateScheme() {
    this.schema.properties.stringProp = {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'I\'m a string',
        description: 'This description is used as a help message.',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for me as well after adding ".bind(this)" to the end, like that:
this.schema.properties.stringProp = {
            type: 'string',
            title: 'I\'m a string',
            description: 'This description is used as a help message.'
        }
     }.bind(this)
Thank you!